# MOSS and Reporting Services

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, performancepoint

Can I provision reporting services reports to MOSS 2007 or do I need to use Performance Point?

Would love to hear how people have done this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS can be installed in native mode or in SharePoint integrated mode. Regardless, they can live side by side. You don't need PerformancePoint to access SSRS from SharePoint, just a link on the MOSS site to the report (be it in MOSS or in native mode).

Personally, I prefer to install SSRS in native mode, since it's the most flexible. You can then serve reports in MOSS through the [SSRS viewer web part](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=1E53F882-0C16-4847-B331-132274AE8C84&displaylang=en).

Comment: But this has a lot of disadvantages. Then you have to handle 2 layers of security and authentication.